# If F(x)=$\int_0^xf(x)dx$ for $x\in[0,3]$, find $F$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f$ is given by $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
               0,~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
               1, ~~~1<x\leq 2 \\
               2, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}$$
If F(x)=$\int_0^xf(x)dx$ for $x\in[0,3]$, find $F$.

Attempt:

As f has only two point of discontinuity, so f is Riemann integrable on $[0,3]$.
Then 
$$ F(x)=\int_0^xf(x)dx=\begin{cases}
               \int_0^x 0\, dx,~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
               \int_1^x 1\,  dx, ~~~1<x\leq 2 \\
               \int_2^x 2\,  dx, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}=\begin{cases}
               0,~~~ 0\leq x \leq 1\\
               x-1, ~~~1<x\leq 2 \\
               2x-4, ~~~2<x\leq 3
            \end{cases}$$

Not getting the answer correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for $2< x \le 3$,

$$\int_0^x f(t) \, dt = F(2)+\int_2^x f(t) \, dt$$